# How to limit the subreport area (width, height) in main report

Tags: crystal-reports

That am using the 2 sub reports in the main report if in one sub report having more no. of rows means it is overlapping on the other subreport in the main report or suggest me how to make it variable of size of the subreport or to make limit of size

Comment: To avoid overlapping place subreports into different sections. To avoid growing height you should be able untick 'Can grow' in subreport formatting options. Subreport width is limited by you in designer.

Comment: i think dat is not work in the case of subreport , it takes in mainreport only, i have used it.,

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. To avoid closing question, please provide some visual cues, what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @Arvo solution works as per the question